# Delphi 10 Seattle app crash with XCode 7.01 Instruments: "Allocations"

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

To trace memory consumption for my iOS app (iPad) made with `Delphi 10 Seattle` I use the `Instruments` tool included with XCode. Specifically the `Allocations` instrument.

The app runs fine both standalone and when debugging from Delphi, but since upgrading to `XCode 7`, it will no longer run with Instruments "Allocations" (it did work with XCode 6.x).

The iPad console shows these messages:

```
Oct  9 09:14:40 iPadMini-A7 DTServiceHub[574] <Error>: kernel symbolicator unable to open /mach.release.s5l8960x
Oct  9 09:14:40 iPadMini-A7 DTServiceHub[574] <Error>: Device Info Service was unable to create symbolicator for the kernel
Oct  9 09:14:40 iPadMini-A7 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:MyApp[0x4936][621]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Oct  9 09:14:40 iPadMini-A7 DTServiceHub[574] <Warning>: -[DTObjectAllocService startCollectionWithPid:]: Unable to configure target process for recording
Oct  9 09:14:40 iPadMini-A7 SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:MyApp[0x4936]' crashed.
Oct  9 09:14:41 iPadMini-A7 ReportCrash[622] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[621] MyApp
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by the `paserver hotfix`:
http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30398